# Increase Tableau online Query execution time

Tags: google-bigquery, execution-time, tableau-api

Is there any way to change query execution time on tableau online. I have to extract 100 M records from Google Bigquery which will take around 3 hr on tableau online but my process stops after 2 hrs with error com.tableausoftware.nativeapi.dll.TableauCancelException: Operation canceled

which is query execution time limit

Comment: Why do you want to extract 100 M records to Tableau? You want 100 M individual points in one visualization?

Comment: Actually, I am creating an ad-hoc report. so I need all the data from which user can choose accordingly just by drag and drop

Answer (score 1):

My #1 suggestion is to make sure your BigQuery tables and queries are optimized as much as possible. Your question doesn't give details on your schema design, query, or indexing, but that is the first place to start. Look at the query plan and timeline to get an idea of where the bottlenecks are in the query execution.

My #2 suggestion is to look at what aggregations your visualizations are doing and see if you can offload that aggregation to the database instead. That will reduce the amount of data needed in your extract file.

Tableau has an excellent Knowledge Base article on this topic, found at https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-operation-cancelled-query-time-resource-limit-7200-refreshing-tableau-online-extract. Much of my answer below is copy/pasted from the KB article.

Here are some options that the KB article gives. Options 3 is easy to do and can make a noticeable difference. Option 2 may be easy to implement, depending on your schema design.

**Option 1**
Use live connections instead of extracts. See [Keep Data Fresh](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_keep_data_fresh.htm) for identifying which cloud-based data sources are capable of connecting live on Tableau Online.

**Option 2**
Use incremental extracts.

**Option 3**
Decrease the size of the data extract. Do this by hiding unused columns and adding filtering to the extract.

**Option 4**
Refresh the published extract using Tableau Bridge, the Command Line Utility, or manually using Tableau Desktop.

**Option 5**
Try scheduling extract refreshes at different times of day, or at night.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. Actually, my query is just a flat fact table from my data warehouse and only contain useful column. Since I am creating an ad-hoc report so I need all the possible columns, and there is no scope of performance tuning. I thought of incremental extract but again 2 hrs limit making me do a lot of manual work. I am planning to go for a live connection though it will cost me a lot on Bigquery end

Comment: If none of these work - extract a CSV to GCS, and import into Tableau.